# How do I make scipy IQR use the difference of the medians of two halves of the array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to work out the IQR of some numbers using scipy's `iqr()` function. However, when I work this out myself I get a different result to IQR, and I think it's because it's not working it out based on the medians. I've looked at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.iqr.html) but can't see anything there.

For example, I have this list:

```
list1 = [7.4, 7.9, 4.1, 8.1, 6.2, 7.1, 7.4, 6.7]
```

If I work out the IQR myself by taking the medians from the upper and lower halves I get `1.2`. If I use `iqr(list1)` I get `0.95`. In this specific case I tried `iqr(list1, interpolation='midpoint')` which gave me the correct answer.

However, I have this second list:

`list2 = [5, 7, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 8, 6, 6]`

and did `iqr(list2, interpolation='midpoint')` but it gave me `3.0` as the answer however I've worked it out to be `4.0`. This was a multiple choice question on an online test I was doing, whether I worked it out right or wrong doesn't matter because `3.0` was not an available answer.

I get the same results as `IQR()` if I work out the IQR doing 75% - 25%, which is not the same as the upper and lower medians. Is there a parameter I have missed or one I can change in IQR to get a consistent answer?

Comment: *"I get the same results as IQR() if I work out the IQR doing 75% - 25%, which is not the same as the upper and lower medians."* - the interquartile range is *[defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range)* as the difference between the 75th and 25th percentiles. I'm not quite sure what you mean by *"taking the medians from the upper and lower quartiles"*, but whatever you're computing it's not the same as the IQR.

Comment: @ali_m wrote *"...the interquartile range is defined as the difference between the 75th and 25th percentiles..."* That definition is unambiguous for a continuous distribution, but for a discrete set of values, the precise meaning is not so clear. What jceg316 wants is to use the difference of the medians of the second half and the first half of the sorted data as the IQR.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes that's correct, I'm looking for the medians of the first and second half of the sorted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following returns the kind of IQR you want:

```
iqr(x, interpolation=('nearest' if len(x) % 4 == 2 else 'midpoint'))
```

A test with 100 different array sizes (sorted arrays, so the difference of medians is easy to find by slicing):

```
for k in range(1, 100):
    x = np.sqrt(np.arange(k))   # some not-too-regular, but sorted, numbers
    diff_medians = np.median(x[len(x)//2:]) - np.median(x[:(len(x)+1)//2])
    my_iqr = iqr(x, interpolation=('nearest' if len(x) % 4 == 2 else 'midpoint'))
    assert diff_medians == my_iqr
```

Note that when the array has odd size (not covered by your examples) both "halves" include the middle element, e.g., in `[1, 2, 3]` the two halves are `[1, 2]` and `[2, 3]`; this seemed the natural choice since otherwise we'd be ignoring the middle one entirely.